# JTable can't display database values in java

Tags: jtable

I sure database values are fetched, but it's still nothing to display.
Netbeans 8.1
jdk 1.8.0.74
jre 1.8.0.91

```
       ...
    ...     
        //---------------------------------DataBase------------------------------------------------------------
    }
    public void valuetable()
    {        
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
```

connect to mysql is ok.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM hams";
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            java.util.Vector tableContent = new java.util.Vector();
            java.util.Vector columnName = new java.util.Vector();
            metaData = ps.getMetaData();
            int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) 
            {
                columnName.add(metaData.getColumnName(i));
            }            
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next())
            {
                java.util.Vector rowData = new java.util.Vector();
                for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++)
                {
                    rowData.add(rs.getObject(i));
                }
                tableContent.add(rowData);
            }            
            tableModel = new HAMS(tableContent, columnName);
            jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane(jTable1);
```

All database values are fetched

```
}
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing the notification that the underlying data has changed in your table model. Try adding the following line

```
tableModel fireTableDataChanged();
```

After the line

```
jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane(jTable1);
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks reply, I'm try add

`tableModel.fireTableDataChanged();`

after the line

```
jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane(jTable1);
```

but jTable1 still empty, and show error like picture.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEAfg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

solve problem myself, the solution is based on example in java book
first, at class block, add these code:

```
public MonitorInterface(java.util.Vector data, java.util.Vector columnNames)
    {
        super(data, columnNames);
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    static final int SCROLL = java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE;
    static final int UPDATABLE = java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE;
```

second, at the method:

```
public void tablevalue()
    {
            java.util.Vector col = new java.util.Vector();
            java.util.Vector data = new java.util.Vector();
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                //Connect MySQL JDBC driver
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                //Connect to host
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                //Connect to DB
                ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                //Get row and column info
                metaData = ps.getMetaData();
                int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
                for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++)
                {
                    col.add(metaData.getColumnName(i));
                }
                rs = ps.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next())
                {
                    java.util.Vector rowData = new java.util.Vector();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) 
                    {
                        rowData.add(rs.getObject(i));
                    }
                    data.add(rowData);
                }
                tableModel = new MonitorInterface(data, col);
                jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable(tableModel);
                jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);
                jTable1.setFillsViewportHeight(true);                
                // Close all connect
                rs.close();
                ps.close();
                conn.close();
            } 
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }    
}
```

finally, the database values is show in JTable, but can't auto updata JTable when database insert new data.

```
jTable1.validate();
 jTable1.updateUI();
 jTable1.repaint();
 tableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
```

I try these method, but still no effect.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved.
I create four class in my project, A class is main method for program entrance, B class is gui for display user interface, C class is receive client data, D class is save client data to database.

I create an method for show database values in B class, and insert this code any where in this method,

```
System.out.println("123");
```

Call this method in B class, it's performed once only, even if database value changed, can't show latest value, so, I try call this method in C class, it's worked, show latest values when database values changed period.

I think problem is:

1. B class is show GUI only, need performed once, don't need twice.
2. Because of C class must receive client data continue, so, the latest database values can show in JTable.

Sorry about my pool english.